# Payment gateway in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, payment-gateway

Is there any way to add **PhonePe, Google-PAY and PayTM** all using one package? Or do I need to add all one by one using separate packages.

Comment: if they are all using different API then you need to handle them separately

Answer (score 0):

You can integrate Paytm's JS Checkout solution. Go to Paytm's developer portal and navigate to JS checkout

Answer (score 0):

Use Stripe.js they have also for Reactjs